# How to quickly see what columns in a table have data?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

We are currently undertaking a testing phase which requires us to see if there is any data in each column for each table. Now, the route that is long and labour-intensive is:

```
    SELECT COUNT(Col1), COUNT(Col2)...FROM TABLE
```

Is there any easier way to do this? We can go down this route by concatenating each column name from our data lineage document with the COUNT() function, but we have a lot of tables and a lot of columns in each table, making this a bit unfeasible.

Essentially we just need a count of records in each column for each table, without having to write long COUNT(Col) queries.

Thanks

Comment: SELECT
  a.low_value,
  a.high_value,
  a.NUM_NULLS
FROM
  ALL_TAB_COLUMNS a
WHERE a.TABLE_NAME = <table_name>

Comment: See ALL_TAB_COLUMNS

Comment: Thanks everyone, all solutions provided are pointing us to what we need! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query will return accurate results if the table statistics were recently gathered with the default value for `ESTIMATE_PERCENT`:

```
SELECT utab.table_name
       , tcol.column_name
       , utab.num_rows
from user_tables utab,
     user_tab_cols tcol 
where utab.table_name = tcol.table_name
and utab.num_rows > 0
and  utab.num_rows = tcol.num_nulls;
```

Comment: Perfect, this helped a lot! I have just read the documentation for these tables and it looks like what we need. Thank you

Comment: Bear in mind that `utab.num_rows` and `tcol.num_nulls` are populated by stats gathering. Consequently individual values may be wrong, possibly wildly wrong. How much this matters depends on whether you need exact figures or merely indicative ones.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dynamic query to build the queries.  This will generate all the queries.

```
SELECT 'SELECT COUNT(' || t.column_name || ' ) FROM ' || t.owner || '.' || t.table_name || ';' FROM dba_tab_columns t
```

Answer (score 1):

You can generate all the select statements like so:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN column_id = 1 AND column_id_desc != 1 THEN 'SELECT ''' || LOWER(owner) || '.' || LOWER(table_name) || ''' table_name, ' || CHR(10) || 'COUNT(' || LOWER(column_name) || ') ' || SUBSTR(LOWER(column_name), 1, 26) || '_cnt,'
            WHEN column_id = 1 AND column_id_desc = 1 THEN 'SELECT ''' || LOWER(owner) || '.' || LOWER(table_name) || ''' table_name, ' || CHR(10) || 'COUNT(' || LOWER(column_name) || ') ' || SUBSTR(LOWER(column_name), 1, 26) || '_cnt FROM ' || LOWER(owner) || '.' || LOWER(table_name) || ';'
            WHEN column_id_desc = 1 THEN '       COUNT(' || LOWER(column_name) || ') ' || SUBSTR(LOWER(column_name), 1, 26) || '_cnt' || CHR(10) || 'FROM   ' || LOWER(owner) || '.' || LOWER(table_name) || ';'
            ELSE '       COUNT(' || LOWER(column_name) || ') ' || SUBSTR(LOWER(column_name), 1, 26) || '_cnt,'
       END sql_text
FROM   (SELECT owner,
               table_name,
               column_name,
               column_id,
               row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY owner, table_name ORDER BY column_id DESC) column_id_desc
        FROM   all_tab_columns)
WHERE  <predicates to filter on the tables you're interested in>
ORDER BY owner,
         table_name,
         column_id;
```

This goes through all the tables you're interested in plus their columns and outputs text that will, when taken together, form a select statement for each table.

The text that is output in the sql_text column depends on whether the column in the list is the first or last (or both!); this way you get the full statement which queries each table once, rather than one per table and column.

You can then copy and paste the results and run that as a script.

Answer (score 0):

It's can help you

```
SELECT
  a.table_name,
  a.column_name
FROM
  ALL_TAB_COLUMNS a
WHERE owner = '<your user>'
AND a.SAMPLE_SIZE = a.NUM_NULLS
```